# Не работает '@' на telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

message.txt содержит:

> Все что тебе нужно:
>  @username

Загрузка
`msgtosend = open('_txt/message.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8').read()`

Отправка:
`client.send_message(chat_num, msgtosend, parse_mode='Markdown')`

В телеграме @ отображается как отдельный символ, а **username** подсвечивается. При нажатии на него пишет: имя **sername** не найдено. Это происходит только в desktop версии, с мобильной все хорошо.

Как можно это поправить?

Comment: а что такое `telehon`?

Comment: опечатался telethon

Answer (score 0):

Протестировал на `aiogram` и `telebot`, используя ваш код и ваш текст. Как вы видите на фото ниже - всё работает.

Возможно, проблема в используемой вами библиотеке.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не совсем подходит, так как тут идет рассылка с телеграм аккаунта, а не через бот, используя API ID и API HASH

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что вы хотите использовать его в качестве спам-рассылки, используя Telegram аккаунт?

Comment: Я использую данную функцию, для рассылки по своим рабочим чатам

Comment: Насколько мне известно, такие действия отрицательно воспринимаются политикой Telegram. и караются даже перманентными блокировками номера телефона. Может ли это как-то быть связано? Что это проблема не библиотеки, а Telegram.

Comment: Нет. Другие участники чата жалуются, что не могут перейти по упоминанию с ПК версии, хотя с телефона переход осуществляется.

Comment: Тогда проблема в desktop версии Telegram.

Comment: Если отправлять упоминание в ручную, то оно работает. Если же через программу, то выходит проблема описанная выше